# Python - merge two data frame issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two data set in python using pandas merge function and i am getting some weird error that im unable to resolve. Can you please take a look and let me know what am i doing wrong here?

Here is the list of the columns of first data set and the type of the data:
FIFA DATA SET

```
Nationality        object
Name               object
Age                 int64
Overall             int64
Potential           int64
Club               object
Value              object
Wage               object
Preferred Foot     object
Weak Foot         float64
Skill Moves       float64
Position           object
Jersey Number     float64
Joined             object
Weight             object
dtype: object
```

And here is the second data set:
GDP DATA SET:

```
Nationaility     object
Population       float64
GDP              float64
dtype: object
```

Here is the code i have used:

```
 master_df = pd.merge(fifa_subset, gdp_subset, on = "Nationaility", how = 
 "right", suffixes=('_',''))
```

And i am getting this error:

```
 C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in 
 __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, 
 right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
 549         (self.left_join_keys,
 550          self.right_join_keys,
 -->  551          self.join_names) = self._get_merge_keys()
 552 
 553         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce

 C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in 
 _get_merge_keys(self)
 855                             right_keys.append(
 856                                 right._get_label_or_level_values(
 -->  857                                     rk, stacklevel=stacklevel))
 858                         else:
 859                             # work-around for 
 merge_asof(right_index=True)

 C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in 
 _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis, stacklevel)
 1380             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
 1381         else:
 ->   1382             raise KeyError(key)
 1383 
 1384         # Check for duplicates

 KeyError: 'Nationaility'
```

Comment: You have two different column names, so you need `left_on='Nationality', right_on='Nationaility'`, or you can rename the column without the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ALollz commented above, here's the complete code if you decide to keep the column names as they are.

```
master_df = pd.merge(fifa_subset, gdp_subset, left_on = "Nationality", right_on = "Nationaility", how = "right", suffixes=('_',''))
```

Comment: thecruisy: [questions about a simple typo](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on SO get closed very quickly, and answering them will not earn rep.

Comment: I feel so embarrassed right now. It was literally the typo issue and i spent hours trying things to troubleshoot but because the way i mistype the words were so similar and my eyes didnt catch it. Thank you both so much and I apologize for wasting your time on something so simple.

Comment: @Slavisha it happens to us all. The good thing is that you did provide a [mcve] so it was simple to find the issue. Happy coding!